# How to calculate a key with integer value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to calculate 2 values with key from SharedPreferences.
This is my code

This is my first activity

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(A1, option_scoreA1);
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This is my second activity

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(A2, option_scoreA4);
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, TestFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

This is my final activity

```
protected QuestionActivity activity1;
protected SecondActivity activity2;

String c = activity1.A1;
String b = activity2.A2;

String A = c + b ;

@Bind(R.id.hasil)
TextView hasil;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    total();
}

public void total() {
    hasil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasil);
    hasil.setText(A);
}
```

I want to totalize each value from key A1 and A2. But what i got was the key, not the value when I totalize them.

Thank you

Comment: thats because you need to get he values for those keys from SharedPrefrences and then add them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you add or concatenate the keys into variable **A**. And you want to calculate the int so you should better put the total result into float or int data type, right?

Do something as shown below

very fist of all make two keys as your instance filed in QuestionActivity class

```
public static final String KEY_A = "ka";
public static final String KEY_B = "kb";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int a = sharedPreferences.getInt(QuestionActivity.KEY_A, 0);
    int b = sharedPreferences.getInt(QuestionActivity .KEY_B, 0);
    A = a+b;

    total();
}
```

and since it is integer, you need to cast the result into string format.

```
public void total() {
    hasil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasil);
    hasil.setText(String.valueOf(A));
}
```

[SharedPreference starting guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: I've tried this, but i didn't get the value from each key, the result is 0

Comment: did you try this line while accessing the sharedPreference SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); ?

Comment: make sure you gone through this guide, because there are so many ways you can go wrong about @Bind https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: try after removing these lines @Bind(R.id.hasil)
TextView hasil;

Comment: it's still not working, i try to debug it. I still got the value 0. This variable doesn't get value of Key A1 and A2

Comment: if it solved your problem, then it should be taken as answer, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

access to value in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

int value1 = preferences.getInt("your key", default_value);
int value2 = preferences.getInt("your key", default_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create sharedpreferences and then get values of your keys.

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

int c = pref.getInt(A1, 0) // here A1 is the key and 0 is default value
int b = pref.getInt(A2, 0) // here A2 is the key and 0 is default value

int A = c + b;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but i didn't get the value from each key, the result is 0. I fill the A1 key with 4, and A2 1.

Comment: can you show your code where you declared A1 and A2